# How to tell express js to use webpack + react as frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

so far I have webpack and express js server. I wanna mix them because I'm looking to implement socket io. What I'm looking for is to use node+ express js on backend and webpack + react on frontend. I've heard about some middlewares, but couldn't find a final answer, any github link or tips are highly appreciated ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very nice and simple boilerplate by Christian Alfoni (author of Cerebral and WebpackBin) that uses the stack you seem you are looking for:
https://github.com/christianalfoni/webpack-express-boilerplate

Comment: This looks really nice and seems to be what I'm looking for! If you don't mind, why is there a production config? I've heard about two type production and development, but I'm not that sure about those two..

Comment: Glad that it helps!
Webpack comes with very handy features for development, like hot reloading, that you don't need in production. The same way, in production there are other good practices to follow, like uglifying js files, that you don't need in development